# Tie the session ID to the SSL session

Tags: tls, vulnerability, session-management

[The OWASP website](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Cookie_Theft/Session_Hijacking) says:

> Tie the session ID to the SSL session and provide configurable options
>   for actions to take if the session ID is transmitted over a new SSL
>   session.

I am not sure if this is actually valid. Can this actually be a useful protection against session hijacking?

Also, I am afraid that by doing this the application functionality might break.

What do you think?

Comment: This post suggests why this is impractical: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2885177/413180

Comment: @SilverlightFox thank you very much! Based on that and the fact that the SSL Session ID can legitimately change for a number of reasons during a valid HTTP session, I believe that tying the SSL/TLS session ID to the HTTP session ID is not going to solve Session Hijacking and most probably is going to create trouble by breaking the normal application flow.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2885177/413180) gives some insight onto this.

Namely that the SSL session identifier could be regenerated at any time, at the discretion of the browser. If this happens during a login session, then this would have the effect of logging out the user.

On the reverse side, it might be useful to detect if a single SSL session is being used for multiple sessions, as a way of detecting a user upto no good. However, IP addess is sufficient and more reliable as a means of flagging possibly malicious activity.

Comment: An IP address can change during a session as well. Carrier-grade NAT, load balanced proxy farms etc. Afaik, a random session id stored as cookie is the only reliable session identifier - which also is hijackable.

But, why should it not be possible to reissue a new cookie id for each request (like a nounce), and if two clients use the same session id, the server can quicky spot that one of the clients are not updated with the new session identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at FIDO and features listed at BrowserAuth.net

http://www.browserauth.net/channel-bound-cookies

Both offer out of band (not accessible  to Javascript) session IDs that offer more/better alternatives.